# La página localhost ha rechazado la conexión

Tags: php, html

He creado un formulario en html, el cual envía información a un programa php que está guardado en la carpeta `xammp/htdocs`, y ya configure xammp con el puerto `8080`.

Pero al ejecutarlo, llenar el formulario y enviarlo me sale el siguiente error:

> La página localhost ha rechazado la conexión.

Aquí esta mi código html.

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/htdocs/ordenarvector.php" method="post">
     Dato 1: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato1"/> <br/>
     Dato 2: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato2"/> <br/>
     Dato 3: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato3"/> <br/>
     Dato 4: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato4"/> <br/>
     Dato 5: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato5"/> <br/>
     Dato 6: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato6"/> <br/>
     Dato 7: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato7"/> <br/>
     Dato 8: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato8"/> <br/>
     Dato 9: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato9"/> <br/>
     Dato 10: <input type="text" name="dato10"/> <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Presiona aquí."/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu servidor está corriendo en el puerto 8080 entonces la URL debe tener ese puerto en cuenta:

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/htdocs/ordenarvector.php" method="post">
     Dato 1: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato1"/> <br/>
     Dato 2: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato2"/> <br/>
     Dato 3: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato3"/> <br/>
     Dato 4: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato4"/> <br/>
     Dato 5: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato5"/> <br/>
     Dato 6: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato6"/> <br/>
     Dato 7: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato7"/> <br/>
     Dato 8: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato8"/> <br/>
     Dato 9: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato9"/> <br/>
     Dato 10: <input type="text" name="dato10"/> <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Presiona aquí."/>
</form>
</body>
```

Si el `DocumentRoot` apunta a `htdocs` entonces deberías cambiarlo por:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/ordenarvector.php" method="post">
```

Pero más sencillo aún: si el PHP del formulario está en la misma ruta que el del que recibe los datos, entonces puedes usar:

```
<form action="ordenarvector.php" method="post">
```

También puedes conocer en todo momento el puerto en el que debes enviar la petición con `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

no es necesario agregar el `/htdocs` en tu url ya que apache automaticamente detecta que el path en donde se encuentran tus archivos es la carpeta htdocs.

Deberia bastar con modificar la url a la que envias la peticion quitando el /htdocs.

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/ordenarvector.php" method="post">
  Dato 1: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato1"/> <br/>
  Dato 2: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato2"/> <br/>
  Dato 3: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato3"/> <br/>
  Dato 4: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato4"/> <br/>
  Dato 5: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato5"/> <br/>
  Dato 6: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato6"/> <br/>
  Dato 7: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato7"/> <br/>
  Dato 8: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato8"/> <br/>
  Dato 9: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="dato9"/> <br/>
  Dato 10: <input type="text" name="dato10"/> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Presiona aquí."/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Lo he hecho y marca el mismo error :(

Comment: @EstebanVera Tu servidor xampp esta corriendo en Windows o Linux?

Comment: Está corriendo en Windows

Comment: @EstebanVera Comentas que configuraste el servicio en el puerto 8080? trata agregando :8080 a tu url. 

http://localhost:8080/ordenarvector.php

Comment: @EstebanJuarez, debieras editar tu respuesta añadiendo lo del puerto. De lo contrario es una respuesta errónea y te van a "llover" los votos negativos. En SO Español nunca llueven votos pero es una figura retórica.

Answer (score 0):

la carpeta se llama **htdocs**, pero cuando haces la prueba no es necesario escribir el nombre de la carpeta(htdocs), por que ahi es donde se encuentra tu servidor llamdo **localhost**, por lo tanto debes hacer referencia a **localhost** directamente, para solucionar modifica esta parte:
 `<form action="http://localhost/htdocs/ordenarvector.php" method="post">`

por esto `<form action="http://localhost/ordenarvector.php" method="post">`

Comment: Lo he hecho y marca el mismo error :(

Comment: @EstebanVera apache esta corriendo?